On Virtual machines - how safe is client data from host access?
Virtual machine systems like KVM or VMware have become more common over the decades, and with falling CPU and memory costs seem like a no-brainer for most internet services today.
One basic question about data security, just looking at the Linux world:
Can the host (root user) look into processes and data of the clients?
In other words, how can a VM system hinder the host (/service provider) to look into (/classified /precious) client data?

Hyper-V has had this feature starting with 2016 (Shielded guest). VMware has Virtual Machine Encryption since vSphere 6.5. These features are expensive. Also Shielded guests has very little market penetration, probably due to it is incompatible or inconsistent with the current state of security in most environments.

@Greg Askew - with "expensive" you mean computing-expensive?
Would this hold true for the AMD hardware solution mentioned below?

no, the cost in person hours to create the very complex product.


Can the host (root user) look into processes and data of the clients?

In traditional security models: yes. Root can at will dump all of system memory, halt execution, peek at CPU registers and so forth. You cannot have secrets from the operating system.

In other words, how can a VM system hinder the host (/service provider) to look into (/classified /precious) client data?

There's emerging support for encrypted VM's that doesn't require trusting the host.

Thanks for the explanation, and hint on memory encryption.
This makes much sense, but seems to be exclusive to AMD EPYC Processors. My current hosting service does not offers these (yet).
Will watch the market.
